# Comparing nested object using “should” library

Tags: c#, mstest

I am running my unit test case and comparing objects using "Should" library. https://github.com/erichexter/Should

```
    class Source
    {
        public List<string> Columns { get; set; }
        public List<EmployeeOne> EmpList  { get; set; }
    }


    class Target
    {
        public List<string> Rows { get; set; }
        public List<EmployeeTwo> ManagerList  { get; set; }
    }

    class EmployeeOne
    {  
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Address { get; set; }
    }

    class EmployeeTwo
    {  
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

after assignment I say

Source.Columns.ShouldEqual(Target.Rows); /// This works fine

**How can I compare
  "Source" EmployeeList with "Target" ManagerTargetList ??**

Obviosuly I can use reflection and for loop but I want to acheive this using **Should library.**

Comment: Did you try `Source.EmpList.ShouldEqual(Target.ManagerList)`? If it fails, how particularly does it fail?

Comment: It says "The type arguments for method 'Should.ObjectAssertExtension<T>(T,T)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type argument explicitly"

Comment: Is it the actual code of the classes that you are using or is it a demo? It will be easier for people to answer if it's the code that you are actually having problems with

Comment: No.The code is different but its the same scenario.

Comment: Do `EmployeeList` and `ManagerTargetList` properties have the same type?

Comment: No. They are NOT. That's the problem. I know where are going with this. I just updated the question to indicate they have different types. Otherwise I think i could have done something like this: Source.EmpList.ShouldEqual<List<CommnType>>(Target.ManagerList);

Comment: @Dyppl: Thank you looking into this issue :)